# What is the error in my work for this related rates problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

[image: Related Rates Question]

[image: Related Rates Work]

I have no clue why my math isn't working out and it is very frustrating. I feel as if I have the concepts correct; however, I just keep getting the wrong answer. Help?

Comment: What do you think the correct answer is / why do you think that you are wrong? (Side note: It might have been easier to let $ D = 45, h = 2$ be constant from the start.)

Comment: Its 15m from the building so your $d$ is not $15$ its $30$...does that fix it?

Comment: He is 15 m from the building. It looks like you are using 15 m from the light.

Comment: Oh wow I should've read the problem closer that makes sense thanks guys

Comment: He is fifteen meters away from the wall after 5 seconds. Where do you use this fact? (Since you need to calculate $\frac{dH(t)}{dt}|_{t=5}$)